# Mu Online level up guide

Tags: mu-online

Can anyone provide a good level up guide comprising each class in [Mu Online](http://muonline.webzen.com) ? What I want is basically a table relating level to training spots or strategies. I am using free servers, not paying for items with real money or accessing gold channels.

Comment: Have you tried typing in "mu online leveling guide" in google? It returns quite a few results.

Comment: @Simon I have only found low level guides (level 1 to 70 or so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This website](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/) has detailed strategy guides for leveling each class in Mu Online:

- [Agility Elf](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/search/label/Agility%20Elf)
- [Energy Elf](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/search/label/energy%20elf)
- [Dark Knight](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/search/label/Dark%20Knight)
- [Dark Wizard](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/search/label/Dark%20Wizard)
- [Magic Gladiator](http://muonline-tutorials.blogspot.com/search/label/Magic%20Gladiator)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but their level guides are only until level 60 or so.